# Software to convert Powerpoint slideshows to images?

Tags: conversion, microsoft-powerpoint, photos

Is there any software out there that is able to convert a Powerpoint slideshow (either in 2003 or 2007 format) to a series of JPG or PNG images?  I'm looking for either standalone software that can do this from the command line, or ideally a .NET library that can be utilized to do the conversion (not holding my breath on that last one).

I know that Powerpoint itself can do the conversion, but it's something I'm looking to integrate into a web application **that can't rely on PowerPoint itself being installed**.

I've done some searches out there, but all I can really find are either instructions on how to do this in Powerpoint, or software itself that looks like its from a very shady source.

Comment: What about Screenshot/Mspaint?!

Comment: I need something that's command-line based as it needs to be integrated into other software.  Specifically I have a web application that would allow the user to upload the powerpoint file and convert it to images for later use.

Answer (score 2):

Its a two step solution, but it does work:

1. Convert *.ppt, .pptx to PDF. [PostScript or GhostScript]
2. Convert PDF to JPG or PNG.  [PDFtoImage]

Both of the above mentioned software are commandline and do exactly as you request. Alternatively, you can install a PNG printer and send the presentations to that. [I do not know how to install one, but i'm sure i saw a tutorial somewhere.]

Answer (score 2):

Install [PDF Creator](http://www.pdfforge.org/products/pdfcreator/) (it's free and relatively lightweight) and follow [these](http://www.aeonscope.net/2007/05/08/pdf-creator/) instructions that would allow you to use it from the command line.

If you can use it from the command line it would make it rather easy to integrate in your app. Just send the command to print the Powerpoint file as jpg or png.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenXML SDK can do this for you off of a web server. Take a look at the source code of http://pptx2silverlight.codeplex.com/ for an example of how this fella does this for a PowerPoint to Silverlight conversion and just uses the PNG export of the slides as his "slides".